# How to avoid cross-checks

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have several jobs to run (pseudocode):

```
public bool IsJob1Running;
public void DoJob1(...) { IsJob1Running = true; ... ; IsJob1Running = false; }

public bool IsJob2Running;
public void DoJob2(...) { IsJob2Running = true; ... ; IsJob2Running = false; }

...
```

In some cases only single job can run at a time, in others - multiple can run, but others shouldn't run (should wait or refuse to start). All this at some point lead to monstrous checks like this:

```
if(!IsJob1Running && !IsJob2Running && !IsJob3Running ... ) { ... }
```

Those are suddenly appears everywhere in the software: when user click button (or even before to disable button), before starting job, even inside `DoJob`, etc.

I hate it. Imagine a case when new `Job99` has to be added. Then everywhere in the software all checks has to be updated to include `Job99` checks.

My question: is there a pattern existing to define this kind of cross-checks (relations?), which will allow to add new jobs easily, have centralized overview of all dependencies, etc.?

### Edit

To give an example:

> Job 1, 2, 3 can run simultaneously, but not when job 4 is running (you have to check if job 4 is running before starting 1, 2 or 3 and vise-versa). Then there are job 5, 6 and 7, only one can run, when job 5 is called from within job 1 it shouldn't be called from  within job 2.

Comment: Why don't you make an `IsAnyJobRunning` method? And why do you make boolean variables for every job, why don't you just have a single filed `CurrentRunningJob`?

Comment: @TamasHegedus, an example: job 1, 2, 3 can run simultaneously, but not when job 4 is running (you have to check if job 4 is running before starting 1, 2 or 3 and vise-versa). Then there are job 5, 6 and 7, only one can run, when job 5 is called from within job 1 it shouldn't be called from  within job 2. This leads to all those `if`s.

Comment: What's a "Job"? Is it a separate class or a method? Who is responsible for starting jobs?

Comment: Why don't you first move responsibility into a JobScheduler class? Then you may add constraints to each job (in base class) and you will simply write if (scheduler.CanRu<Job99>())

Comment: @AntonGogolev, for simplicity it's a method, but in reality those are different classes (*models*). Job can be started by user (clicking button), automatically in case certain condition is met (inside polling monitoring thread or in event handler).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, don't start `Job` directly, but call it via `JobSheduler`? Wow.. sounds cool. Why didn't I though about this?

Comment: Ok, so the problem is that the connection between jobs is complicated. I am afraid there is no other way but modeling the problem at a higher level. You could introduce job types as higher level abstractions, and define exclusion between job types, not individual jobs. If you can't find/there isn't a higher level model, then you are doomed with the complexity. Maintaining such a system is a nightmare and will only get worse.

Comment: Not mentioning it's difficult to reason about correctness if the system is described with thousands of different conditions. Some higher level model would also ensure less bugs

Comment: @Sinatr I remember I saw a similar question about job scheduling (in a very complicate scenario) here on Stack Overflow (or Code Review? I can't find it now...) If you find it you may pick some nice ideas from there

Comment: @TamasHegedus, can you give an example of how to define exclusions? Do you mean to group similar job, e.g. instead of `MoveUp` and `MoveDown` (which can not occurs at same time) introduce single `MoveVertically`? Or what is this higher level abstraction would be?

Comment: @Sinatr Exactly, those are the kind of job types i was thinking about. Im at work right now but I will try to provide some example code later, maybe tomorrow. Dont wait for me, If you find a good solution just go ahead.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement something like the base job class:

```
public abstract class BaseJob 
{
    public bool IsRunning { get; private set; }

    public void Run() 
    {
        IsRunning = true;
        RunInner();
        IsRunning = false;
    }

    public abstract void RunInner();
}
```

and then inherit all your jobs from this:

```
public class LoadUserDataJob : BaseJob
{
    public override void RunInner()
    {
        // load user data
    }
}
```

Then, you will be able to have a list of actions over your jobs:

```
// Check if there is any running task
if (jobsArray.Any(j => j.IsRunning))

// Check if there is a task of type LoadUserDataJob running
// Use Where->Any instead of Single if there are many jobs of this type
if (jobsArray.Where(j => j is LoadUserDataJob).Any(j => j.IsRunning))
```

You can also combine this with some kind of `Task` and use `Task.WaitAny`, `Task.WaitAll` in order to provide waiting for execution.

Talking about an universal framework or pattern, which will automatically detect and check job dependencies, sequences and execution order, then I cannot imagine one - it strongly depends on your business logics and types of your jobs.

Comment: I have already base class to avoid repetitive code when defining, starting, progressing or finishing jobs. This is not my problem. My problem is only logic to start the job. Putting related (similar?) jobs into list and using `Any` is good idea. Adding new job means only adding it to lists, no need to rewrite any `Any`.

Answer (score 1):

Configuration of the dependencies between the jobs is a separate issue, but you could extend your base class to include a static list of all jobs, along with a few instance properties that describe under what conditions a specific job should run.  For example:

```
// All instantiated jobs should be added to this list, regardless of whether they're running.
public static List<BaseJob> AllJobs { get; private set; }

// These jobs must be running for the current job to start:
public List<BaseJob> MustBeRunning { get; private set; }

// These jobs must not be running for the current job to start:
public List<BaseJob> CannotBeRunning { get; private set; }

// This overrides the previous two lists to indicate whether the
// job must not run concurrently with any other job (prevents you
// from having to add every other job to "CannotBeRunning":
public bool MustRunIndependently { get; set; }

// Update your run method to take all of this into consideration:
public void Run()
{
    if (MustRunIndependently)
    {
        if (AllJobs.Any(x => x.IsRunning))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("This job must run independently.");
        }
    }
    else if (MustBeRunning.Any(x => !x.IsRunning))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Required concurrent jobs are not running.");
    }
    else if (CannotBeRunning.Any(x => x.IsRunning))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Incompatible jobs are currently running.");
    }
    // If we made it here, then it's okay to run the job.
    IsRunning = true;
    RunInner(); // overrided by inheritors to perform actual job work.
    IsRunning = false;
}
```

Comment: This sounds like making manager. It's not clear how to populate those conflicting lists. Are they populated by each job? So each job knows all other jobs? How process of adding `Job99` would looks like?

Comment: @Sinatr, the population of the lists would probably happen by whatever component is instantiating the job instances.  I would imagine this would be some kind of configuration-processing component.  For example, jobs might be configured via some XML file, and that XML file would specify the dependencies between the jobs.  The component that processes the XML file would be responsible for instantiating the job instances and populating their lists appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

This problem could be solved by implementing a *Job scheduler*.

They way I'd approach it is implementing a scheduler with a *pending jobs* queue and a *currently executing jobs* list. Jobs would be enqueued in the pending jobs in order of arrival and the scheduler would be responsible of checking if the next pending job is authorized to run by examining the currently executing jobs and transferring from *pending* to *executing* and launching it accordingly.

You'd need some callback mechanism to signal when jobs are finished and should be cleared from the *executing list* by the scheduler:

```
public abstract class Job
{
     public event EventHandler<MyFinishedJobEventArgs> JobFinished;

     public void Run()
     {
         var e = new MyFinishedJobEventArgs(...);
         OnRunJob(e);

         if (JobFinished != null) JobFinished(this, e);
     }

     protected abstract void OnRunJob(MyFinsishedJobEventArgs e); //Job logic goes here.
}
```

The tricky part here of course is getting synchronization right with decent performance.

Concering the rules that define what jobs can be run or not, if they are all of the type *JobX can't run while JobY and JobZ are running*, then this could be easily policed in the scheduler by keeping track of job incompatibilities; i'd use a `Dictionary<Type, IEnumerable<Type>>`

```
void RegisterIncompatibility(Job job, IEnumerable<Job> incompatibleJobs)
{
     incompatibilities.Add(job.GetType(), incompatibleJobs.Select(j => j.GetType());
} //I prefer registering jobs instead of types to somehow ensure type safety.
```

Now the scheduler should simply check before launching the next job for any current incompatibilities:

```
private bool canRunJob(Job job)
{
    //omitted null checks, contains key check, etc.
    if (executingJobs.Any(j => incompatible.Contains(j.GetType())))
       return false;

    return true;
}
```

This should be reasonably easy as long as you preserve execution order. That is, first job enqueued is the first job to run and it will block all other pending jobs until it is allowed to run.

If you need to skip jobs that are currently not allowed to run and execute other pending jobs until conditions are met then things do start to get hairy.

Comment: I like the idea of scheduling execution, but why it must be a queue? In my case most of jobs should rather return error (if conflicting job is running) than to wait (and waiting is actually a simple blocking of caller). Base job class to inherit all jobs from with `IsBusy` property and events for starting/progress/finishing, then `Scheduler` with `DoJobX()` method overloads for each job (and bunch of `if` to define logic what to allow to run). Will it be a poor design? Why queue, list of conflicting jobs and complexity of synchronization? To gain what?

Comment: @Sinatr because I don't know the *exact* nature of your problem. This is a general case approach, if your case can be simplified you will know better than anyone. Do consider though that this approach could cover a very broad scenario; for instance you could  add to `Job` a property `CancelIfUnableToRun`. For those jobs with the property set to `false`, they would block the queue until allowed to run, all others would be removed from the queue if `CanRun` fails and the callback would flag the error. You get both behaviors.